# Android: Using Timer to send SMS at regular intervals, but SMSes does'nt stop?

Tags: android, timer, sms, intervals, repeat

I wanted to send sms repeatedly at regular intervals, `Handlers` and others can be used as far as what Google told me, but I figured `CountDownTimer` function is far more simpler.
I placed the timer in a function and called that function in the `onFinish()` function of the `CountDownTime`r.

The problem is the SMSes are continously being sent even if back button is pressed or I tried to end it by clicking a button and finishing the activity(this.finish()), but of no use.

If I could just figure out how to stop the timer by pressing a Custom `Button`, my purpose would be served.

Placing `timer.cancel()` in the `onClickListene`r is force-closing the app rather than stopping the timer.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mTextField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mTextField);
    endbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.end);
    timerFunc();



}

public void timerFunc()
{
  new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("Next Msg in " + millisUntilFinished/1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
     //   mTextField.setText("Done!");
     //   String finalMsg = "Hii at" + System.currentTimeMillis();
      //  sendMsgFunc(finalNumber, finalMsg);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        timerFunc();
    }


 }.start();



 end.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        // WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE SO THAT I CAN END THIS CURRENT SESSION    
                       OF  COUNTDOWN. i.e Stop Sending messages at that interval?

    }
});

}    

}
```

If I wanted to end it by a button? Should the code be?

```
endbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        cdt.canel();
    }
```

Comment: `endbutton.setOnClickListener` seems to be outside onCreate

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the count down timer.

```
public final void cancel ()

Added in API level 1
Cancel the countdown.
```

Have a instance variable `CountDownTiemr cdt`.

Then

```
cdt = new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {...
```

Then `cdt.cancel()`.

Also you have  `timerFunc()` in `onFinish()`. Suppose the count down finished you start the timer again. Is that what you want?

`Handler` is a better choice.

Comment: if cdt.cancel() is placed in endbutton, the app forcecloses
and if cancel function is declared seperately, what should be in that function?

Comment: @user3557410 post the stacktrace